# What index is buildout really using?

Tags: python, buildout, pypi

I'm trying to install couchdbkit using following buildout config:

```
[buildout]
parts = eggs
include-site-packages = false
versions = versions

[eggs]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:eggs
eggs =
    couchdbkit

[versions]
couchdbkit = 0.6.3
```

It installs package successfully but I get numerous errors like this during setup *on some machines*:

```
Download error on http://hg.e-engura.org/couchdbkit/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
```

Be default buildout should find packages using [this](http://pypi.python.org/simple) index. But I can't understand source of this weird hostname. Nothing [here](http://pypi.python.org/simple/couchdbkit/) points to this location.

How does it actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying `setuptools` code also scans for `homepage` and `download` links from the [simple index](http://pypi.python.org/simple/couchdbkit/) and does this quite aggressively.

The [`couchdbkit` `setup.py` file](https://github.com/jeremi/couchdbkit/blob/master/setup.py) lists `http://hg.e-engura.org/couchdbkit/` as the homepage, so all `homepage` links on the simple index link there.

You can prevent `zc.buildout` from trying to connect to that host by setting up a whitelist of hosts it *can* connect to:

```
[buildout]
# ...

allow-hosts =
   *.python.org
   *.google.com
   *.googlecode.com
   *.sourceforge.net
```

for example.